# Making Cost Surface Distance map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, cost-surface, least-cost

Projection is in NAD 83- units of measure in meters.

I have major roads NC vector data overlaid on Forsyth county in North Carolina.

[image]

I would like to create a cost surface distance map using this major roads field. I converted the major roads vector to raster format using measured distance of each road in miles as the field value. 
[image]

Next, I converted the major roads raster from miles to meters using calculator (divided by 0.0006213). To find the cost surface, I input Forsyth county as source data, major roads raster as input cost raster, and I received an output cost map with unrealistically high values. If I can get help to find the correct cost map that would be great. 
[image]
[image]

Comment: From the picture of your table it looks like you are using ArcMap so I'm going to tag your question for that and Spatial Analyst. Please always write the software you are using as part of your question body.

Comment: Make raster under road equal 1, outside 1000. Compute cost distance. From it subtract euclidean distance to roads/1000.